# Split on newline, but not space-newline

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split on a newline character, if it is not directly preceded by a space. For example:

```
CA, The title\n # yes
CA, the title \n # no
```

To split on any newline, I can do `lines = contents.split('\r\n')`. How would I do the amended split?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use negative look-behind assertion. Quoting the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) doc,

> **`(?<!...)`**
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is not preceded by a match for `....` This is called a *negative lookbehind assertion*

So your RegEx would work like this

```
data = """CA, The title
CA, the title 
data"""

import re
print re.split(r'(?<!\s)\n', data)
# ['CA, The title', 'CA, the title \ndata']
```

Here, `(?<!\s)` tells the RegEx engine that, match the string following this, only if it is not preceded by `\s` (which means any whitespace characters).

Quoting the documentation for `\s`, from [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) doc,

> When the `UNICODE` flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace character, this is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`

Comment: I posted that here first

Comment: Also, `\s` will match not just space, but any whitespace character [ \t\n\r\f\v] plus any Unicode whitespace chars.

Answer (score 4):

Simple `string.split` won't discriminate because it can't lookbehind at any preceding context.

You need `re.split`, with a regex with a negative lookbehind assertion that the `\n` was not preceded by a space.

```
s = 'CA, the title \nCA, The title\nCA, the title\n'
re.split(r'(?<! )\n', s)
['CA, the title \nCA, The title', 'CA, the title', '']
```

Answer (score 3):

With a negative lookbehind.

```
>>> contents = 'CA, The title\nCA, the title \nCA, The title\n'
>>> re.split(r'(?<! )\n', contents)
['CA, The title', 'CA, the title \nCA, The title', '']
```

Comment: I posted that here first

Answer (score 0):

You could use positive lookbehind also. `\S` matches any non-space character.

```
>>> s = 'CA, the title \nCA, The title\nCA, the title\n'
>>> re.split(r'(?<=\S)\n', s)
['CA, the title \nCA, The title', 'CA, the title', '']
```